# Lua OpenTX custom menu

Tags: lua

I am making a lua telemetry script for OpenTX RC transmitter, and i would like to create a custom menu after the user press a button. I figured out how to check for button clicks but i would like to know if there is any function to create a custom menu for me.

I found function `popupInput(title, event, input, min, max)` in opentx github documentation but when i call this function nothing seems to happen.

I want something like the stock menu that is in the OpenTX system [image]

Here you can see a menu with options Reset telemetry and Reset flight i want to make something similar.

So is there any way of creating custom menu ?? or do i have to do all the drawing and handling of input by myself ??

Comment: SO needs "OpenTX" tag.

Comment: But there is no such tag and i dont have the reputation to create one

Comment: you might want to share your code, your firmeware version... also consider asking this in the opentx community as this is very special. have you checked their chat or mailing lists?

Comment: No not yet but i just stopped searching and start coding my own function to do it :). I will share it after its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on finding function that would do my thing and instead make my own

Here is the function:

```
local function drawMenu(items, event)

  local maxLen = 0;
  local itemCount = 0;
  for index, action in pairs(items) do
    itemCount = itemCount + 1;
    if string.len(index) > maxLen then
      maxLen = string.len(index);
    end
  end

    local width = maxLen * 5; -- width of the menu frame
    local height = (itemCount * 9) + 2; -- height of the menu frame
  if event == EVT_EXIT_BREAK then
    menu = false;
  end

  if event == EVT_PLUS_BREAK or event == EVT_ROT_LEFT then
    selected = selected + 1;
  end

  if event == EVT_MINUS_BREAK or event ==EVT_ROT_RIGHT then
    selected = selected - 1;
  end

  count = 0;
  actions = {};

  lcd.drawFilledRectangle((LCD_W/2) - (width/2), (LCD_H/2) - (height/2), width, height, ERASE);
  lcd.drawRectangle((LCD_W/2) - (width/2), (LCD_H/2) - (height/2), width, height, SOLID);
  for index, action in pairs(items) do
    actions[count] = action;
    if count == selected then
      lcd.drawText((LCD_W/2) - (width/2) + 3, (LCD_H/2) - (height/2) + (count * 8) + 2, index, 0+ INVERS);
    else
      lcd.drawText((LCD_W/2) - (width/2) + 3, (LCD_H/2) - (height/2) + (count * 8) + 2, index, 0);
    end
    count = count + 1;
  end

  if event == EVT_ROT_BREAK or event == EVT_ENTER_BREAK then
    actions[selected]();
    menu = false;
  end

  if selected >= count then
    selected = 0;
  end
  if selected < 0 then
    selected = count - 1;
  end

end
```

It accepts array of functions with string index. The index is the name in the menu, the function executes when the user selects it. The size of the menu is codded poorly so it might be sometimes too much wide.

To make it work you also need a global variable menu which should controll the menu visibility. You should turn the menu on by:

```
local menu = false;
local function run_func(event)
  if event == EVT_MENU_LONG then
    menu = true;
  end
  if menu then
    drawMenu(items, event);
  end
end
```

and also you need global variable selected.

```
local selected = 0;
```

But this function is not complete it does not support scrolling and it might behave strange when too many items are passed to this function

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: maybe you should find out why popupInput doesn't work or why the popup menu I found a completed feature request for is not available in Lua scripting. but hey having your own thing is nicer anyway. now you have full control

Comment: Thats exactly true. I dont know whats up with the popupInput or even with every other popup method. It does not throw any error or something it jsut executes and nothing happens. I might try to look inside to the lua code on the OpenTX side.